# Elasticsearch: search word forms only

Tags: elasticsearch

I have collection of docs and they have field `tags` which is array of strings. Each string is a word.
Example:

```
[{
 "id": 1,
 "tags": [ "man", "boy", "people" ]
}, {
 "id": 2,
 "tags":[ "health", "boys", "people" ]
}, {
 "id": 3,
 "tags":[ "people", "box", "boxer" ]
}]
```

Now I need to query only docs which contains word "boy" and its forms("boys" in my example). I do not need elasticsearch to return doc number 3 because it is not form of boy.

If I use `fuzzy` query I will get all three docs and also doc number 3 which I do not need. As far as I understand, elasticsearch use levenshtein distance to determine whether doc relevant or not.

If I use `match` query I will get number 1 only but not both(1,2).

I wonder is there any ability to query docs by word form matching. Is there a way to make elastic match "duke", "duchess", "dukes" but not "dikes", "buke", "bike" and so on? This is more complicated case with "duke" but I need to support such case also.

Probably it could be solved using some specific settings of analyzer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With "word-form matching" I guess you are referring to matching morphological variations of the same word. This could be about addressing plural, singular, case, tense, conjugation etc. Bear in mind that the rules for word variations are language specific

Elasticsearch's implementation of fuzziness is based on the [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance). It handles mutations (changes, transformations, transpositions) independent of a specific language, solely based on the number if edits.

You would need to change the processing of your strings at indexing and at search time to get the language-specific variations addressed via stemming. This can be achieved by configuring a suitable an analyzer for your field that does the language-specific **stemming**.

Assuming that your tags are all in English, your mapping for tags could look like:

```
"tags": {
  "type": "text",
  "analyzer": "english"
}
```

As you cannot change the type or analyzer of an existing index you would need to fix your mapping and then re-index everything.

I'm not sure whether Duke and Duchesse are considered to be the same word (and therefore addresses by the stemmer). If not, you would need to use a customised analyzer that allows you to configure synonyms.

See also Elasticsearch Reference: [Language Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html)

Comment: English analyzer would just solve the stemming part ie root part, but would not solve for `plural, singular, case, tense, conjugation` etc

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja According to the official documentation (see link above for the `english` analyzer)  the Elasticsearch bull-in analyzer `english` has stemming configured

Comment: Yeah I know and have used it extensively and that's what I mentioned in my comment `English analyzer would just solve the stemming part ie root part` :-)

Comment: Well, `stemming` is all about reducing morphological variants (caused by singular, plural, tense, conjugation, etc.) into a root form aka `stem`. However, `stemming` does not "understand" a language and does not result in the linguistically correct root forms, it's always an "approximation". Alternatively, `lemmatization` could be used to reduce morphological variants of a word to so-called `lemmas`, which represent the linguistically "correct" root form. Afaik there are no free `lemmatizers` available for European languages.

Comment: Thanks you two. I'm going to try this. I'll return with news about this case

Comment: That worked for me! Now I can type "boy" in search and elastic will return docs with "boy" tag.